# Kivy reload image

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I'm creating a simple app which grabs a string and turns it into a qr code yet I can't get my application to return updated qr image. File IS updated but even though I call .reload(), image displayed as a result is still previously created one.

I believe that during startup application is being built with image that is currently stored, one from the previous ran, why isn't .reload() updating it though? Am I using it correctly?

On the side note: is there a way to increase debug verbosity so I can see python errors not only kivy's? Running everything through try: is kinda overwhelming.

```
class Note(Screen):
def reload_image(self):
        w = NoteCode().ids.image
        w.reload()
def qr_generator(self):
    note_input = self.note_input.text
    inn = pyqrcode.create(note_input)
    with open('qr.png','w') as inputfile:
        inn.png(inputfile,scale=8)
    self.reload_image()
```

And corresponding kv:

```
<Note>:
    note_input:note_input
    name:"Note"
GridLayout:
    rows:3
    cols:1
    Label:
        size_hint_y:0.15
        text:"Create a QR Note"
    TextInput:
        id:note_input
    GridLayout:
        size_hint_y:0.15
        rows:1
        cols:2
        Button:
            text:"Back"
            on_release: app.root.current = "Main"
        Button:
            text:"Generate"
            on_release: root.qr_generator()
            on_release: app.root.current = "NoteCode"


<NoteCode>:
    name:"NoteCode"
    GridLayout:
    cols:1
    rows:2
    Image:
        id:image
        allow_stretch:False
        source:'qr.png'
    Button:
        size_hint_y:0.1
        text:"Back"
        on_release: app.root.current = "Note"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me this line `w = NoteCode().ids.image` seems problematic as you create a new instance in there and don't get aleary existing one, therefore even if you reload something, it won't be the `NoteCode` that's used in the layout most likely. You need to access `NoteCode` either through some `id`, or put this to its `__init__`:

```
self.app = App.get_running_app()
self.app.notecode = self
```

and then in `Note.reload()` do this:

```
app = App.get_running_app()
w = app.notecode.ids.image.reload()
```

You can put the app in init too or basically anywhere you like, the important is to get the right instance.